# Laravel Too few arguments to function App\Policies\RolePolicy::update()

Tags: laravel

this is in my role policy:

```
public function update(User $user, Role $role)
{
  return $user->hasPermissionTo('update role') && $role->name != 'admin';
}
```

and this is in my edit.blade.php

```
@can('update role',$user)

...

@endcan
```

but i get the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Policies\RolePolicy::update(), 1 passed in C:\laragon\www\myblog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 740 and exactly 2 expected
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this

```
@can('update role',$user)
```

to this

```
@can('update',$role)
```

`$user` will be automatically passed to the policy method.